# How to print Dictionary from Input?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I am only a few weeks into learning Python so please bear with me.

I have created a set of dictionaries, and I would like the user to be able to search the name of one (via `Input`) and then `Print` the whole dictionary.

I can see where the issue is, when I'm entering the `Input` it's assigning it to it's own variable, then calling that to `Print`... is there any way I can take the value and display the dictionary with that variable name?

```
DICT001 = {
     'MAP' : 'XXXX',
     'SSC'   : '0333',
     'Method': 'R',
     'Code1': 'S093733736',
     'Reg ID'  : '01'
}

DICT002 = {
     'MAP' : 'XXXX',
     'SSC'   : '0333',
     'Method': 'H',
     'Code1': 'B19SN99854',
     'Reg ID'  : 'S'
}

Search = input("Enter Dictionary to Search:")

print (Search)
```

I understand completely why the code above doesn't work at all, its just printing the Search Variable I've created... However I can't seem to find any work around for this anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to input "DICT001" and then print the corresponding dictionary?

Comment: Store both dictionaries as entries in another dictionary: `dict_lookup = {'DICT001': DICT001, ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ***Short answer:***

```
c = "DICT001"
tmp_dict = globals().get(c, None)
print(tmp_dict if tmp_dict else "There's no variable \"{}\"".format(c))
```

## ***Extended answer:***

Yes there's few methods how to get value of variable by it's string name, **BUT fact that it's needed usually is marker of bad code.**

Regular way to store such as data will be **nested dictionary**.

**Example:**

```
dictionaries = {
    "DICT001": {
         'MAP' : 'XXXX',
         'SSC'   : '0333',
         'Method': 'R',
         'Code1': 'S093733736',
         'Reg ID'  : '01'
    },
    "DICT002": {
         'MAP' : 'XXXX',
         'SSC'   : '0333',
         'Method': 'H',
         'Code1': 'B19SN99854',
         'Reg ID'  : 'S'
    }
}
```

It allows you to avoid searching for variable. You need just to get value by key in dictionary.

**Code:**

```
c = "DICT001"
tmp_dict = dictionaries.get(c, None)
print(tmp_dict if tmp_dict else "There's no key \"{}\"".format(c))
```

Comment: can i know why your answer is a bad code or any links for further study?

Comment: In general variable has name only for convenience of development process. Variable at all is an abstraction for data storage. Possibility to access variable by it's string name is a part of reflection. Same as all features, reflection should be used when it's necessary. Also it takes more time to execute search for variable than to get value by key in dictionary.

Comment: @OlvinRoght That's great, thank you! I get the main points your making, but is there any more reading I can do on this 'tmp_dict' you have used?

Comment: @PyPat848, what do you mean under "reading"? `tmp_dict` contains instance of variable in both code examples, so you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

or better just create a parent dictionary,

```
parent_dict = {
      'DICT001' = {
     'MAP' : 'XXXX',
     'SSC'   : '0333',
     'Method': 'R',
     'Code1': 'S093733736',
     'Reg ID'  : '01'
      },
      'DICT002' = {
     'MAP' : 'XXXX',
     'SSC'   : '0333',
     'Method': 'H',
     'Code1': 'B19SN99854',
     'Reg ID'  : 'S'
 }
}

search = input("Enter Dictionary to Search:")
if search in parent_dict:  
   print(f'here\'s you dict {parent_dict[search]}')
else:
   print('child dictionary not found')
```

Comment: Why `search in list(parent_dict)` or `search in parent_dict.keys()` which are O(N), when you can just `search in parent_dict` in O(1) which is **exactly** what dictionaries were designed for?

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` and `locals()` are dictionaries containing all `globally` and `locally` defined variables respectively. You can use either of them for your use case.

Example:

```
globals()['DICT001']
```

OR to avoid error if dictionary not present do this:

```
globals().get('DICT001', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you want to have your dictionaries **separated**, i suggest you this way that i tried and pleased me! This code i wrote **takes the name of a dictionary from user** and print the corresponding dictionary.
I suggest you to make another dictionary so it has only the names of your variables(your dictionaries):

```
dict1 = {#some informations}
dict2 = {#some informations}
dict3 = {#some informations}
dict4 = {#some informations}
```

now i build dictionry_collection:

```
dictionary_collection = {
    "dict1" : dict1, #the first one is the key and second is value(the made dictionaries)
    "dict2" : dict2,
    "dict3" : dict3,
    "dict4" : dict4
}
```

now i can take the user choice which is string:

```
user_choice = input("Enter the name of dictionary you want to print: ").lower()

chosen_dict = dictionary_collection.get(user_choice, "Dictionary NOT Found!!")

print(chosen_dict)
```

Notice: The **get()** method is a dictionary method that **retrieves the value associated with a given key**. In this example it retrieve the value of **user_choice** from **dictionary_collection** and put it into **chosen_dict**.
you can do this to understand it better:

```
print(type(chosen_dict))
```

Comment: This solution is the same as the one presented in [Olvin Roght's (accepted) "extended answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949845/4450498) as well as in [P.hunter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949964/4450498).